# How can users login after creating users in ldap server?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed openldap server. 
created users in the server with cn, sn, userPassword attributes. 
Now how can the above users login to ldap? what will be their credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you want to login. The idea behind ldap is to get the user directory so you can define which fields to use for your specific needs, but knowing the user database is separated to be used for different services.

Now, **normally** a way to login into the user (like phpadmin services) uses the `DN` and its respective passwords. The `DN` **normally** should be a combination of `cn=myuser,dc=ldap,dc=server,dc=com`, where you need to assign those parameters with your respective variables.

Comment: When I try to login/bind users with their dn and password I get insufficient access rights. I configured my slapd.conf file to give access to them like : ` access to *  by * read `. Yet I get the same message. Could you tell me what I might be missing. @eLRuLL